# Insert the same item in multiple rows in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to be able to insert the same string in consecutive rows of some column of an org-table. I am using spacemacs and there is a vim way to insert the same instances in all visually selected areas, but is their maybe a more elegant way to insert the same string into multiple selected rows of a specified column in an org-table using spacemacs?

kind regards